# Horários de atendimento ou horários de atendimentos?

Tags: ortografia, substantivos

A dúvida está a flexão da palavra atendimento. É comum vermos a expressão horários de atendimento.

> Exemplo:
>   Os horários de atendimento da agência X são: ...

Essa oração está correta?

Ou seria:

> Os horários de atendimentos da agência X são: ...

Devemos flexionar a palavra atendimento nesse caso?

Comment: Sim está correta, acho que a segunda também. Acho que também poderia ser "O horário de atendimentos". Embora soe estranho acho que são as três válidas. Mas vou deixar para quem sabe explicar :)

Comment: O atendimento é um serviço como em: "Os horários de manutenção foram programados", é uma locução que tem seu uso registrado desta forma no singular. Para flexionar atendimentos teria de usá-lo como um substantivo: "Os atendimentos da agência serão em tais horários". Outra forma de perceber que atendimentos deve ser singular é colocar agência no plural: "Os horários de atendimento das agências são" ou "Os horários de atendimentos das agências são...", aqui a segunda frase parece a correta pois cada agência tem seu próprio atendimento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se calhar também não sou o melhor exemplo.

Mas, pense na lógica gramatical: se for só um HORÁRIO, sem mudanças penso que o singular é bem aplicado visto que não há uma variação do tempo de abertura e fechamento.
Se forem vários tempos de abertura, por exemplo, já seria HORÁRIOS.

Atendimento, para mim, já tem mais consenso que seja singular porque o atendimento só vai ser um, não sei se haverá uma excepção. Talvez se só estiver a explicar as várias vezes que lá foi. Por exemplo: aqueles horários malucos estão sempre a mudar e os atendimentos são péssimos.

Portanto:
Os horários de atendimento da agência X são: ...

OU

O horário de atendimento da agência X é: ...

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [Portuguese SE](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/)! Sendo este um site sobre a própria língua portuguesa, peço que observes mais a pontuação em suas respostas. Editei sua resposta, podes conferir as alterações [aqui](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/3401/revisions). Caso eu tenha alterado o sentido, podes desfazer as alterações.