# Qual é o correto? loja de roupa ou loja de roupas?

Tags: gramática

Qual é o correto? loja de roupa ou loja de roupas?

Fiz uma pesquisa e os dois termos aparecem com muita frequência. Será que os dois termos têm significados diferentes?

Comment: Depende de quantas roupas estamos falando...

Answer (score 2):

Pergunta bastante semelhante a esta [Horários de atendimento ou horários de atendimentos?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/hor%c3%a1rios-de-atendimento-ou-hor%c3%a1rios-de-atendimentos)

Penso que a nível gramatical as duas estão totalmente correctas, a diferença penso que resida apenas numa questão de significado ou de ênfase da frase.

Penso que ao dizer "loja de roupa**s**" parece dar-se algum peso ao facto de haver "várias roupas" ou vários tipos, de diferentes qualidades ou variedades de produtos, enquanto que "loja de roupa" não parece ter qualquer segundo significado subjacente.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas são aceitáveis, por que "roupa" pode ser usado tanto como algo contável como não contável:

- Comprei duas roupas novas ontem.
- Mandei dois quilos de roupa para a lavanderia.